# Change panel border color at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem is that i am trying to change a panel border color upon the activation of a textbox placed inside, any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event `Click` of your TextBox (use the Property window from Form designer).

Then add the code:

```
    private void textbox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(panel1.CreateGraphics(), panel1.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
```

Obviously you can change the trigger event and adjust the color on your needs.

Comment: Maybe use the `Enter` event instead of `Click` -- This: `panel1.CreateGraphics()` is not good

Comment: @Jimi With the `Enter` event if the textbox is the first being focused at window startup, the event fires unintentionally. What is an alternative to `CreateGraphics()`?

Comment: The TextBox is focused at startup if it's the only Control that can receive focus and also in this case it appears this is the intent: *change a panel's border color upon activation of a textbox* -- `panel1.CreateGraphics()` is not good for 2 main reasons: 1) The Graphics object is not persisted, so if you, for example, minimize and restore the Form, that border goes 2) If you use `CreateGraphics()`, you need to dispose of the Graphics object (need = must) -- It would be better to use a Custom Control that overrides `WM_NCPAINT` or a UserControl that contains a TextBox.

Comment: A Custom Control that handles `WM_NCPAINT` because you're not actually drawing a border (non-client area), but a rectangle inside the client area (try to set the Panel's BorderStyle to `FixedSingle`). You can use `GetWindowDc()` and `Graphics.FromHdc()` to owner-draw the border (without calling `base.Wndproc()`) -- I understand that this may be beyond the purpose of this post.

Comment: A simplified alternative is to use the `Enter` and `Leave` event of the TextBox(es) to just `Invalidate()` the Panel(s), moving `if (textBox1.Focused) { ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ...); }` in the `Paint` event of the Panels(s) -- This - after a couple of TextBox + Panel things - explains why the suggestion about a UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using the the **enter** and **leave** event of the **text box** as follow.

In the **enter event**

```
this.searchPanel.BorderStyle=BorderStyle.None;
        this.searchPanel.Refresh();
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(
            graphics: this.searchPanel.CreateGraphics(),
            bounds: this.searchPanel.ClientRectangle,
            color: System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0,120,215),
            style: ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

And in the **leave event**

```
this.searchPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.searchPanel.Refresh();
```

***Before*** [image]
***After***[image]